# Trouble creating MYSQL view

Tags: mysql, view

First off, the version of MYSQL I'm using is `5.1.66-community-log`.

Now that we got that out of the way, I'm retrieving the following error when trying to create the below view:

> **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'all  select RRA.id, RRA.reply_id as replyID, RRA.user_id,
>   RRA.vote_up, RRA.rank' at line 4**

and the view:

```
$sql = "Create or replace view userRank as 
select PRA.id, PRA.post_id as postID, PRA.user_id, PRA.vote_up, PRA.rank_date 
from post_rank_activity PRA
union all 
select RRA.id, RRA.reply_id as replyID, RRA.user_id, RRA.vote_up, RRA.rank_date 
from reply_rank_activity RRA";
```

I've checked a few sites and this seems to be the correct syntax - or has something changed over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses may helps, try :

```
Create or replace view userRank as 
(select PRA.id, PRA.post_id as postID, PRA.user_id, PRA.vote_up, PRA.rank_date 
from post_rank_activity PRA)
union all 
(select RRA.id, RRA.reply_id as replyID, RRA.user_id, RRA.vote_up, RRA.rank_date 
from reply_rank_activity RRA)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,32218,32353), your *all* is not needed, try:

```
Create or replace view userRank as select PRA.id, PRA.post_id as postID, PRA.user_id, PRA.vote_up, PRA.rank_date from post_rank_activity PRA union select RRA.id, RRA.reply_id as replyID, RRA.user_id, RRA.vote_up, RRA.rank_date from reply_rank_activity RRA;
```

and it should work -- untested.

Answer (score 0):

Union All column in all sections have to be similar in name and type

These two are different

- **PRA.post_id as postID**
- **RRA.reply_id as replyID**

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug even raised at MySQL Site

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22044